# Variable Argument List in Between as a Parameter with different data type

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I was working with varargs and came to know that :-

```
public void myMethod(String... args, int val){}
```

> The variable argument type String of the method myMethod must be the
>   last parameter.

If both will be like `String`, error its giving is considerable, But in this case, I am setting `int` as 2nd parameter, so at runtime `JVM` can check the type of arguments & can differentiate like :-

```
myMethod("HI", "HELLO", 9)
```

Wouldn't that be feasible. Any other point I am missing for this to be producing error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a number of reasons why the language designers have chosen to disallow this:

1. Differentiation has to be done by the compiler, because varargs are entirely a compiler feature. They are simply converted to implicit array constructors.
2. Your example could in theory work out, but the restrictions would be very harsh: For example, it would be hard for the compiler to see where the first varargs parameter ends in a situation like this

   ```
   void foo(Object... objs, String... s)
   foo("a", "b", "c")
   ```

   Another example is this:

   ```
   void bar(int... ints, long... longs)
   foo(1, 2, 3, 4)
   ```

   You could argue that `int` and `long` are different data types, but unfortunately it is possible to use integers where `long` is expected due to widening conversions. And another example involves boxing:

   ```
   void baz(Object... objs, int... ints)
   baz(1, 2, 3, 4)
   ```

   `int` and `Object` are not directly related, but `int` can be converted to `Integer`, which is a subclass of `Object`.
3. It gets even more complicated the more overloaded methods and varargs parameters you have.
4. A bit technical, but still relevant: in the bytecode, `varargs` is not a parameter attribute, but a method modifier flag (`ACC_VARARGS`). This means that either a method is variadic (the last parameter is varargs) or it's not.
5. If you really need a varargs parameter in your method, move it to the last position. The only situation in which you couldn't do this is when you have multiple varargs parameters, which is impossible for a good reason.
6. If the compiler would allow you do this at declaration-side without an error, it should be almost impossible to get a useful error at use-site.
7. `String...` is the same as `String[]`, except that you don't need to create an array at use-site. You can declare a method

   ```
   void foo(String[] strings, int i)
   ```

   and call it as

   ```
   void foo({ "a", "b" }, 2)
   ```

   with just 2 more keystrokes, and without all the struggle introduced by varargs parameters.

I have been working on a [JVM-language](https://github.com/Dyvil/Dyvil) compiler for more than a year now, and I considered adding this feature as well. However, the method resolution system is *already* extremely complicated (and my decision to include custom `infix` and `prefix` operators / methods and named and default parameters doesn't make it any easier), and multiple varargs parameters wouldn't make it any easier.

Comment: Thanks. Cleared a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is correct.  If you use varargs, it has to be the last argument.  You could say it could work it out, but it won't.  Just swap the order of your arguments.

Comment: Yeah but actually wanted to know the reason for the above. Curiosity, it kills

Answer (score 0):

Disambiguation will become a nightmare when you overload methods with varargs in random positions... (not to say multiple varargs).

Answer (score 0):

This is specified in the JLS, [section 8.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1).  The language specification calls for this as part of a formal parameter list:

> ```
> FormalParameterList:
>     ReceiverParameter 
>     FormalParameters , LastFormalParameter 
>     LastFormalParameter
> ```

The `LastFormalParameter` token is where varargs are defined and permissible.

> ```
> LastFormalParameter:
>     {VariableModifier} UnannType {Annotation} ... VariableDeclaratorId 
>     FormalParameter
> ```

Pay attention to the `...`.  That's the only place in the grammar of formal parameters in which this is allowed.  `FormalParameters` does not make that allowance.

> ```
> FormalParameters:
>     FormalParameter {, FormalParameter} 
>     ReceiverParameter {, FormalParameter}
> ```